# PIGPIO bit banging UART - SLR to plaintext

Tags: python, uart, pigpio, bit-bang

I've managed to read UART input by SLRO and SLR commands from pgpiod, however, SLR returns UART bit-banged data in the following format:
[number of read bytes] [bytes]

http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html#SLR

I need to read this bit-banged uart into a variable in a python script, and I need this data to be in plaintext (real characters), instead of decimal (bytes). How to read data with SLR in Python in such a way, that I can store the data as text in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like

```py
count, data = pi.bb_serial_read(SERIAL_GPIO)

if count > 0:
   my_string = data.decode()
   print(my_string)
```

Comment: Does pigpio have the decode function?

Comment: `decode` is standard Python.